# C# - SocketIoClientDotNet - Connection is never upgraded to WebSocket

Tags: c#, websocket

I have a simple code that I am testing against a socket.io server (chat.socket.io)

```
    IO.Options testOptions = new IO.Options();
    string url = "http://chat.socket.io";
    testOptions.ForceNew = true;
    testOptions.AutoConnect = true;
    testOptions.Upgrade = true;

    Socket _socket = IO.Socket(url, testOptions);

    _socket.On("data", (data) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());
    });
```

When I look at the connection through fiddler I see the transport is only polling
I have no Idea why

Also about every 2 minutes the client disconnects and reconnects

Comment: I am facing the same issue. OrM where you able to resolve it?

Comment: No, I moved to a different lib